# Server returned HTTP response code: 415 Unsupported media type

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I have a rest web service like below.

```
@POST
@Path("/startProcess")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String startProcess(InputParams inputParams, @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {       
   ProjectBean projBean = new ProjectBean();
   Helper.loadProjectBean(inputParams, projBean);
   return "1";
}
```

Now I am trying to consume it with below main program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    String taigaServiceUrl = "http://localhost:8181/restServer/rest/TestWebService/startProcess/";
    URL url = new URL(taigaServiceUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    String userpass = "admin" + ":" + "admin";
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
    InputParams inputParams = new InputParams();
    inputParams.setXXX("xxxx");
    inputParams.setYYYY("123456");
    inputParams.setZZZZ("ZZZZ");
    String json = new Gson().toJson(inputParams);
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream (conn.getOutputStream());
    os.write(json.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    br.close();
}
```

But every time I am getting below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: http://localhost:8181/restServer/rest/TestWebService/startProcess/
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at scm.controllers.Test.main(Test.java:64)
```

As per error the media type is unsupported. In my rest webservice I am consuming JSON and in my main program I am sending JSON. Then where it is breaking?

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but you might need to add request header/property `Accept: text/plain`, and you might need to drop the `/` at the end of the url. Also, do not use `DataOutputStream` (you're not doing primitive Java data types anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after lot of debugging I found solution of my problem. I needed to add below jars in classpath. Actually Jersey was not able to bind JSON object to the rest service.

```
jackson-annotations-2.5.4.jar
jackson-core-2.5.4.jar
jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar
jackson-jaxrs-base-2.5.4.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.5.4.jar
jersey-entity-filtering-2.22.2.jar
jersey-media-json-jackson-2.22.2.jar
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at this guide:

I think you need to define a json processor:

```
https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/java-ee/producing-and-consuming-json-or-xml-in-java-rest-services-with-jersey-and-jackson
```

thanks.

Comment: What makes you think the server doesn't already have a JSON processor? HTTP error code 415 is a [content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) error, not an server error for missing processor.

Comment: As stated above by OP , the issue was that the processor could not be found , so my suggestion was on the right track. Not sure why I was down voted.

Answer (score -2):

This is the issue with your @Produces and @Consumes. 
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
As per the annotation, your endpoint receives JSON and result would be TEXT.

But in your client program, you have mentioned content type as json.
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

Hence client expects a json, where as its not.

Change this as 
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");

would work.

Comment: You're mixing client and server. When server `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`, the client has to set `Content-Type: application/json`. When server `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`, the client has to `Accept: text/plain`.

Comment: The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.

Comment: The program which expose the endpoint produces the content of "text/plan". (sets with annotation  @Produces )  Where as the program which consumes the endpoint expects "application/json" (sets in your main program setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); )

Comment: `Content-Type` is used to specify the type of the data you're *sending*, not the data you're *expecting*. The *"program which consumes the endpoint"*, aka the *client*, needs to *send* data in a format (specified by `Content-Type`) that the *server* is expecting to *receive* (specified by `@Consumes`).